# Dividing table rows to different columns according to their value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table id, gra, grb integers and NOT NULLS and contain DIFFERENT numbers between 1 and 10.
I'd like to divide the data from gra and grb to different columns according to their value.

example: mysql table:

```
+------------+------------+------------+
| id         | gra        | grb        |
+------------+------------+------------+ 
| 1          | 2          | 6          |
+------------+------------+------------+ 
| 2          | 10         | 8          |
+------------+------------+------------+ 
| 3          | 9          | 5          |
+------------+------------+------------+ 

etc
```

The expected table output would be like this:

```
+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| gr1        | gr2        | gr3        | gr4        | gr5        |gr6         | gr7        |gr8         |gr9         |gr10        |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|            | 2          |            |            |            | 6          |            |            |            |            |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|            |            |            |            |            |            |            | 8          |            | 10         |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|            |            |            |            | 5          |            |            |            | 9          |            |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

Is there an easy way to do this? I figured I could do this using mysql with CASE function but it'd be too long. I think there should be an easier way. Can I get help with this, please? thanks.

Comment: This is just a meaningless bunch of numbers. What is going on here? What's the algorithm you're applying?

Comment: I need to divide the data from gra and grb to different columns (gr1-gr10) according to their value from 1 to 10.

Comment: What if `gra` and `grb` are identical? Or NULL? You need to clarify more. I'd start by using PHP and a string buffer populated with a sufficient number of spaces, then start replacing parts of the string with the numbers at the calculated positions. Then print.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention they can't be identical. they are all different. and they are not null.  i update my question.

Comment: This task is known as *pivoting*. In MySql it's a notorious pain in the neck. Your observation about using CASE being too long is true. But, still, that's the way you do it.

Comment: ok. thanks a lot!  I'll do it with Case function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the desired result using this approach

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli('hostname', 'username', 'password', 'dbname');
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$sql    = "SELECT gra ,grb FROM `tablename`";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$rows   = array();
$i = 0;
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    foreach(range(1,10) as $key => $value){
        $_key = 'gr'.$value;
        $rows[$i][$_key] = ($row['gra'] == $value) ? $row['gra'] : ( ($row['grb'] == $value) ? $row['grb'] : null);
    }
    $i++;
  }
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($rows);
```

You can print in a table like this

```
$sql    = "SELECT gra ,grb FROM `grade`";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$rows   = array();
$i = 0;
$html = '<table border="1"><tr>';
foreach(range(1,10) as $v){
  $html.= '<td>gr'.$v.'</td>';
}
$html .= '</tr>';
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $html .= '<tr>';
  foreach(range(1,10) as $key => $value){
    $_key = 'gr'.$value;
     $rows[$i][$_key] = ($row['gra'] == $value) ? $row['gra'] : ( ($row['grb'] == $value) ? $row['grb'] : null);
     $html .= '<td>&nbsp;'.$rows[$i][$_key].'&nbsp;</td>';
   }
   $html .= '</tr>';
   print_r($rows[$i]);echo '<hr>';
   $i++;
 }
}
$html .= '</table>';
echo $html;
```